# paypal sdk 'Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found'

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement paypal api sdk using this code

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$api = new ApiContext(
 new OAuthTokenCredential(
    'client id',
    'secret'
 )
);

$api->setConfig([
 'mode'=>'sandbox',
 'http.ConnectionTimeOut'=>30,
 'log.LogEnabled'=>false,
 'log.FileName'=>'',
 'log.LogLevel'=>'FINE',
 'validation.level'=>'log'
]);
```

The Rest and Auth folders are subfolders of PayPal folder which exists inside the vendor folder. But I get this error "Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are still facing this issue, but I would recommend going through the documentation mentioned [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation).
This should help you find the reason why you are getting this error.

Also, [making your first call](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call) documentation would really help get you started.

Answer (score 6):

Same error here. Solved reading the documentation:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$api = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    $client_ID,
    $client_Secret
  )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case of Laravel implementation, adding this solved my problem:

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Download the SDK using Composer
2. Re-Upload the Vendor directory in the App root

Comment: There is a working solution described  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400764/fatal-error-class-paypal-api-payer-not-found-en-sdk-paypal/47776518#47776518  by Olga.