# Paypal + FB API installed via Composer. Autoload broken?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I first installed the PayPal API using Composer and managed to get the PHP code working:

```
<?php

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    'xxx', 
    'xxx')
);

?>
```

And I added this to the Index.php page

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

As I said this used to work. Then I installed the FB API using the following Composer Json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "1.10.0",
        "facebook/graph-sdk" : "~5.0"
    }
}
```

The FB is working but I can't seem to use the PayPal API anymore. I deleted the entire Vendor dir and uploaded it again on the server. The vendor/autload.php file looks likes this:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit303a6e73ffa85ad916995f78100e5117::getLoader();
```

First I don't know why the file doesn't end with a `?>`? Is this normal?

When I try to call my `paypal.php` file I get the infamous error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in ...
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here, but PHP files lacking a closing `?>` are perfectly fine. In fact, this is considered a best practice on PHP-only files by many developers. See [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-2-files), for example.

Comment: There is a working solution described  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400764/fatal-error-class-paypal-api-payer-not-found-en-sdk-paypal/47776518#47776518  by Olga.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

To the files. Adding to index.php is not enough apparently. It needs to be inserted within the paypal.php file from which the API functions are used.