# PHP Paypal Rest API Composer Installation

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm trying to install the Paypal PHP REST API, by following the instructions on this page.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer

Namely, I'm running this command on composer.

composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"

However, I'm running into this error.

Problem 1
    - The requested package paypal/rest-api-sdk-php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

The instructions aren't working. Does this mean the API has been abandoned?

Comment: try:
composer self-update;
composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"
Also, share you composer.json file please

Comment: No, didn't work

Comment: The instructions work fine for me as is. Composer fires up and I get `Installing paypal/rest-api-sdk-php (1.10.0)` downloaded to my vendor dir.

Comment: There is a working solution described  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400764/fatal-error-class-paypal-api-payer-not-found-en-sdk-paypal/47776518#47776518  by Olga.

Comment: Was this solved ?

Answer (score 0):

composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:

composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

Remove the quote first or install another laravel application and try that again

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use `composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*`

**UPDATE:**

Refer this link for more details : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.